# How to advance to a "new page" using pygtk?

Tags: python, image, gtk, pygtk

I'm new to programming in python, but I've went through tutorials which taught me how to create click-able images and connecting them to trigger a callback function.

I am trying to write a script which will allow me to click an image, and move onto a new window or "page" of different click-able images.

Is there a way for me to do this using pygtk? I thought about creating classes and using an if else statement to poll through classes I wanted to use, but it hasn't worked for me. Or am I suppose to continuously hide and show buttons and images?

Is there a way to modify the sample code I've been using to accomplish my goal?
http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/images.py

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What hasn't worked for you? This question is too unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`GtkNotebook`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html) and [hide](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-set-show-tabs) its tabs. Whenever you need to change page, just [switch](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html#gtk-notebook-set-current-page) the current page of the `GtkNotebook`.